# AspNet.Identity.Samples -Version 2.2.0-alpha1 With Web API2.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

When I add **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Version 2.2.0-alpha1** to my MVC 5.0/Web API project the Web APi stops responding.
What is the reason to this strange behavior? 
Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

After some researches I realized that **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples** packages modifies the configuration process that happens in configuration phase in the beginning of Application life cycle.
So adding 
**GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)** again in Configuration phase of Application life cycle should fix that problem.